# Experiencing intermittent issues hitting repo.spring.io endpoint

Tags: spring

Starting today around 12:00 CST I started seeing intermittent issues trying to pull maven artifacts from https://repo.spring.io.  It presents itself as 403 forbidden but when hitting the URL from the browser you can see a 404 error.  Refreshing returns the expected results followed by another 404 on the next refresh.

https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/

I do see an occasional redirects to jfrog.com with a 403 forbidden error.  Are there any known maintenance activities happening or is this perhaps a known issue that is being worked.  I've talked to developers from other companies experiencing the same issue so it is not isolated to me only.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. From browser it gives 404 followed by success.. From gradle build it always fails.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this same erratic behavior as well -- 404s followed by success; or the index page for an artifact shows the file listing, but will get 404 half the time when trying to download the file from the link presented. A new version of Spring Boot was released today though, so maybe that's related: https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/29/spring-boot-2-4-0-m1-is-now-available

Answer (score 0):

The issues appears to be fixed now.  I assume it was just an intermittent technical issue that was addressed by the Spring team.