# Reason for not being able to resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Java Gradle project, which is throwing this error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':brix-web:classpath'.
    > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE.
      Required by:
          My Project
       > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE.
          > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom'.
             > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

This is actually doing a build on a GitLab server, which happens with every check-in. Usually it works fine. But today I am getting this error.

At first I thought that this is an issue with our company network, but then I saw that even on my laptop (https://repo.spring.io) opens sometimes and sometimes shows me this Forbidden error.

So now I think there's something wrong with the `spring repo` server. Or maybe we are using such an old version that no one is looking after this one?

So how can I confirm if there's something really wrong with the `spring repo` server?

Comment: it looks like something is going wrong with `spring repo`, indeed: I have tried several GET on `https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/` , half of them returned 404 NOT FOUND responses, other returned expected response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646040/experiencing-intermittent-issues-hitting-repo-spring-io-endpoint

Comment: So it seems fine now on 2020-06-30 at 9:30 AM EDT. It wasn't working pretty much the whole day yesterday. Anyway we can get answers as to why was it not working yesterday?